# how to convert list of complex object and represent it in values yaml chart

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have following spring YAML structure:

```
catalogParamter:
  - name: kota
    street: xxx
  - name: yyy
    street: kkkk
```

now I want those values to come from values YAML in helm chart

in spring YAML  catalogParamter: ${CATALOG_PARAMETER}
and defined it in deployment yaml and config yaml

and values coming from values YAML

how to represent  catalogParamter  in values YAML.

Answer (score 1):

There are different options here. I'd suggest putting the [application.yaml in a ConfigMap](https://github.com/trisberg/devoxx-spring-boot-k8s/blob/master/actors/config/actors-config.yaml). You could then expose properties in your values file with:

```
properties:
  catalogParamter:
    - name: kota
      street: xxx
    - name: yyy
      street: kkkk
```

And populate the data section of your ConfigMap with:

```
data:
  application.yaml: |-
{{ toYaml .Values.properties | indent 4 }}
```

You can [then mount that ConfigMap](https://github.com/trisberg/devoxx-spring-boot-k8s/blob/master/actors/config/actors-deployment.yaml#L51) into the `/config` directory so that the spring boot app will [automatically read it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

If instead you use environment variables then you can map complex properties to environment variables with Spring boot's [relaxed binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0). Coding that conversion in your chart could be tricky but your case seems to be name-value pairs so I think it could be done with helm's range function.

Another different pattern is to expose the [option to set env vars directly to the user](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-the-helm-chart-patterns-from-the-official-kubernetes-charts-8a7cafa86d12). But the disadvantage of this is the user would have to understand the env var format, which may not be intuitive with relaxed binding.

Comment: for me it being converted to  [map[customerEntityParameter:customerType parameterType:String catalogParameter:customer.customerType]]                                          where it should be list/array

Comment: Are you getting this error from java? If you're trying to work out what the env var format is then you can try that without kubernetes by setting the environment variables locally and starting your app on the command-line. I guess you're setting something like `CATALOGPARAMETER[0]_NAME=` and `CATALOGPARAMETER[0]_STREET=` ?